# Does a Facebook notification 17% CTR limit apply to an app that **was** over 50 000 notifications, but soon dropped under?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, limit, facebook-insights

I have an app that *used to* **send more than 50 000 notifications weekly and dropped below 17% CTR**. When Facebook blocked the app, we edited and limited the notifications to below 40 000 weekly which increased the CTR to about 20%. **FB unblocked the app and DAU skyrocketed**.

**Today the charts look like FB blocked us again**. While our CTR indeed dropped a wee below 17%, we do not exceed the 50 000 notification limit.

Is it possible that once you exceed 50 000 notifications for the first time, **the 17% limit "sticks"** and haunts you even if you drop below 50 000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just got an answer from a FB developer:

**No, the limit does not stick once you've gone over 50k for the first time. If you go back down to 40k per week afterwards you should have no difficulties.** We look at both click through rate and spam rate when it comes to apps that use notifications, and for more information, if your app is restricted I would recommend submitting an appeal at https://developers.facebook.com/appeal. If your app doesn't appear there, or if there is no notice of restriction on your app dashboard, that means it has not been restricted by us, and there may be something else affecting your notifications.

If you do submit an appeal I'll make sure our team takes a look and we can give you a better explanation. Make sure you keep an eye on the contact email address of your app for our response; you can find this in the Settings tab of your app dashboard if you need to update it.

For more information on notifications in general, I strongly recommend checking out our developer docs, particularly here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications. There's some great tips on how to optimize notifications. We allow apps to send under 50k notifications per week with no CTR requirement because we want to give developers the opportunity to test new notifications before rolling them out to wider audience. We really believe that developers can actually get much higher CTR, usually up in the mid 20's, with careful targeting and thoughtful creative work.

If you're getting that high CTR, that also means you can send notifications to a lot more people who are using your app. So not only are more people getting your notifications, but a higher percentage of people are clicking on them too.